# reset pygame set_timer dynamically

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I'm coding a game in pygame and I want an event to happen on a timer.  I've been using this

```
ms_til_turn = 4000
pygame.time.set_timer(25,ms_til_turn)
```

but now that I want to change the value of the milliseconds til turn variable dynamically, I'm realizing that the timer doesn't change when ms_til_turn changes, it still just triggers the event every 4 seconds.  How can I do this so that I can reset the timer to be a different length?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change `ms_til_turn` just run this line again:`pygame.time.set_timer(25,ms_til_turn)`.